# Vectors vs 2D Arrays vs Array of structs with int* inside.

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm working on a programming question for Hackerrank. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-2d-arrays . I already solved the problem, but like any good developer-in-training, I am looking for advice for best practices of creating a 2d data structure for the fastest code execution.

The question is very simple, and asks to define a shape within a 2-d array and to count the highest value of all the occurrences of that shape.

So, at first, instead of using a vector as they had provided in the template, I used a 2-d array. However, I have some training in pointers, so I made a 2d array with struct pointers like this:

1. Is my solution better than just using regular old 2-d arrays?
2. If so, should I not even put in the effort even for a big project?
3. If not, When should I (ever) opt for this kind of thing?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct row {
    signed int * usePointers;
};

int main() {
    int highest = -324;
    int next;

    row* chart;
    chart = new row[6]; //allocate all rows first

        for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++) {
            chart[arr_i].usePointers = new int[6]; //allocate each column here

            for (int arr_j = 0; arr_j < 6; arr_j++) {
                chart[arr_i].usePointers[arr_j] = 0; //fill each element here
                cin >> chart[arr_i].usePointers[arr_j];
            }
        }

        //create the hourglass (n-3)*(n-3) times
        for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i <=3; arr_i++) {
            for (int arr_j = 0; arr_j <=3; arr_j++) {
                next = 0;
                //top
                next += chart[arr_i].usePointers[arr_j] + 
                    chart[arr_i].usePointers[arr_j+1] + 
                    chart[arr_i].usePointers[arr_j+2];

                //mid
                next += chart[arr_i+1].usePointers[arr_j + 1];

                //bottom
                next += chart[arr_i+2].usePointers[arr_j] + 
                    chart[arr_i+2].usePointers[arr_j + 1] + 
                    chart[arr_i+2].usePointers[arr_j + 2];

                if (next > highest)
                    highest = next;

                //cout << chart[arr_i].usePointers[arr_j];
            }
        }
        cout << highest;

        free(chart);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your solution works, you'd better ask this question on [codereview.se].

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is apparently not C. And what would a "new 2D array" be?

Comment: I used a c-style struct, and make a double pointer. I thought that area of the code was familiar to a C developer.

Also, you also are the only one to say "new 2D array" in the thread, don't abuse quotes, because I searched for it so I could answer your question and found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a fixed sized 2D array, then you should probably simply use something like `int a[6][8]` and have done with it. If you need a dynamic 2D array, it's generally more efficient to allocate the array as one contiguous block of memory and then perform the offset calculations needed to access the array elements yourself. Messing about with arrays of pointers is likely to be slow, because the array will will be located in multiple different areas of memory, and this will defeat CPU cacheing algorithms.